# multiple pipes in loop, saving pipeline-result to array

Tags: bash, pipe, process-substitution

I am trying to do the following (using bash):
Search for files that always have the same name and extract data from these files. I want to store the extracted data in new arrays
I am almost there, I think, see code below.

The files I am searching for all have this format:

```
 #!/bin/bash
  echo "the concentration of NDPH is 2 mM, which corresponds to 2 molecules in a box of size 12 nm (12 x 12 x 12 nm^3)" > README_test

#find all the README* files and save the paths into an array called files
  files=()
  data1=()
  data2=()
  data3=()

  while IFS=  read -r -d $'\0'; do
files+=("$REPLY")
  #open all the files and extract data from them
  while read -r line
  do
name="$line"
echo "$name" | tr ' ' '\n'|  awk 'f{print;f=0;exit} /of/{f=1}' 
echo "$name" 
echo "$name" | tr ' ' '\n'|  awk 'f{print;f=0;exit} /of/{f=1}'
data1+=( "$echo "$name" | tr ' ' '\n'|  awk 'f{print;f=0;exit} /of/{f=1}' )" )    

# variables are not preserved...
# data2+= echo "$name"  | tr ' ' '\n'|  awk 'f{print;f=0;exit} /is/{f=1}'
echo "$name"  | tr ' ' '\n'|  awk 'f{print;f=0;exit} /size/{f=1}'
# variables are not preserved... 
# data3+= echo "$name"  | tr ' ' '\n'|  awk 'f{print;f=0;exit} /size/{f=1}'
  done < "$REPLY"
  done < <(find . -name "README*" -print0)
  echo ${data1[0]}
```

The issue is that the pipe giving me the exact output I want from the files is "not working" (variables are not preserved) in the loops.
I have no idea how/if I can use process substitution to get what I want:
an array (data1, data2, data3) filled with the output of the pipes.

UPDATE:
SO I was not assigning things to the array correctly (see data1, which is properly assigning sth now.) 
But why are

```
echo ${data1[0]}
```

and

```
echo "$name" | tr ' ' '\n'|  awk 'f{print;f=0;exit} /of/{f=1}'
```

not the same?

SOLUTION (as per ilkkachu' s accepted answer):

```
  #!/bin/bash
  echo "the concentration of NDPH is 2 mM, which corresponds to 2 molecules in a box of size 12 nm (12 x 12 x 12 nm^3)" > README_test
  files=()
  data1=()
  data2=()
  data3=()

  get_some_field() {    
 echo "$1" | tr ' ' '\n'|  awk -vkey="$2" 'f{print;f=0;exit} $0 ~ key {f=1}' 
  }

  #find all the README* files and save the paths into an array called files
  while IFS=  read -r -d $'\0'; do
files+=("$REPLY")
  #open all the files and extract data from them
  while read -r line
  do
name="$line"
echo "$name" 
echo "$name" | tr ' ' '\n'|  awk 'f{print;f=0;exit} /of/{f=1}'
data1+=( "$(get_some_field "$name" of)" )
data2+=( "$(get_some_field "$name" is)" )
data3+=( "$(get_some_field "$name" size)" )

  done < "$REPLY"
 done < <(find . -name "README*" -print0)

  echo ${data1[0]}
  echo ${data2[0]}
  echo ${data3[0]}
```

Comment: `data1+= echo...` doesn't really do anything to the `data1` variable. Do you mean to use `data1+=( "$(echo ... | awk)" )` ?

Comment: @ilkkachu yes indeed, you are correct.

Comment: *"The files I am searching for all have this format:"* - Did you mean to include an example of the files you are trying to process?

Comment: @steeldriver because there are many files I am only giving you one example, written in the first line to the file README_test (the files are all one-liner outputs from another program)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you want the output of the `echo ... | awk` stored in a variable, and in particular, appended to one of the arrays.

First, to capture the output of a command, use `"$( cmd... )"` (command substitution). As a trivial example, this prints your hostname:

```
var=$(uname -n)
echo $var
```

Second, to append to an array, you need to use the array assignment syntax, with parenthesis around the right hand side. This would append the value of `var` to the array:

```
array+=( $var )
```

And third, the expansion of `$var` and the command substitution `$(...)` are subject to word splitting, so you want to use parenthesis around them. Again a trivial example, this puts the full output of `uname -a` as a *single* element in the array:

```
array+=( "$(uname -a)" )
```

Or, in your case, in full:

```
data1+=( "$(echo "$1" | tr ' ' '\n'|  awk 'f{print;f=0;exit} /of/{f=1}')" )
```

<sub>(Note that the quotes inside the command substitution are distinct from the quotes *outside* it. The quote before `$1` doesn't stop the quoting started outside `$()`, unlike what the syntax hilighting on SE seems to imply.)</sub>

You could make that slightly simpler to read by putting the pipeline in a function:

```
get_data1() {
    echo "$name" | tr ' ' '\n'|  awk 'f{print;f=0;exit} /of/{f=1}'
}
...
data1+=( "$(get_data1)" )
```

Or, as the pipelines seem similar, use the function to avoid repeating the code:

```
get_some_field() {
    echo "$1" | tr ' ' '\n'|  awk -vkey="$2" 'f{print;f=0;exit} $0 ~ key {f=1}'
}
```

and then

```
data1+=( "$(get_some_field "$name" of)" )
data2+=( "$(get_some_field "$name" is)" )
data3+=( "$(get_some_field "$name" size)" )
```

<sub>(If I read your pipeline right, that is, I didn't test the above.)</sub>

Comment: this works - and the explanations helped me to understand what went wrong :)